# Enterprise Library 5.0 - Creating custom XML template

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-5

I have a vb.net app and I would like to customize XML template using Enterprise Library 5.0 in order to adapt it to my needs for logging. I am trying to create a custom rolling XML Trace Listener (I need one XML file for each day if possible) with the following XML template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<frames>
    <frame>
        <timestamp>20/10/2016 07:30:05 AM</timestamp>
        <content>bla bla bla </content>
        <status>OK</status>
    </frame>
    <frame>
        <timestamp>20/10/2016 15:10:12 PM</timestamp>
        <content>bla bla bla </content>
        <status>FAIL</status>
    </frame>

    ... NEXT FRAMES ...

</frames>
```

How could I do this using Enterprise Library 5.0?

Or maybe it is more suitable and easier to use XmlTextWriter/XmlReader and XmlTextReader/XmlWriter for writting and reading custom XML files respectively?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about the output file format you want but I have created a sample Rolling XML Trace Listener sample that can be used as a starting point: https://github.com/randylevy/Samples/tree/master/EntLib5Samples/Samples.TraceListeners .

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look.